# SQL for grouping by timeframe with empty frames

Tags: php, mysql, time, grouping

My goal is it to create a SQL-Query that counts all items in a certain time frame (e.g. 5min)

That's my code so far:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(timestamp_stop/5*60)*(5*60), '%h:%i') AS timekey, timestamp_stop, count(item) AS performance
FROM task
WHERE done = 1
GROUP BY timekey
ORDER BY timestamp_stop ASC
```

That works great, but doesn't include time frames in which there aren't any records in the database.
I would like to also get these 0-count-ones, up to the current time.

Currently I have no simple/elegant solution in my mind. Any ideas?

Some little post processing in php would also be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If there are such time frame, but the `where` clause filters out the records, you can do:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(timestamp_stop/5*60)*(5*60), '%h:%i') AS timekey,
       timestamp_stop,
       sum(item is not null and done = 1) AS performance
FROM task
GROUP BY timekey
ORDER BY timestamp_stop ASC;
```

If you still have gaps, then you need to generate a table (or subquery) containing the list of the time frames that you want and use `left join`.

EDIT:

A subquery is not pleasant.  You have to list all the time values.  Something like:

```
SELECT q.timekey, t.timestamp_stop, coalesce(t.performance, 0) as performance
FROM (SELECT '00:00' as timekey UNION ALL
      SELECT '00:05' UNION ALL
      . . .
     ) q LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(timestamp_stop/5*60)*(5*60), '%h:%i') AS timekey,
             timestamp_stop, 
             COUNT(item) AS performance
      FROM task
      WHERE done = 1
      GROUP BY timekey
     ) t
     ON t.timekey = q.timekey
ORDER BY timestamp_stop ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks! The gaps are not due to the where clause but due to the lack of any entries. How could a subyquery that has all the time frames look like? The soulution with the extra table is not very elegant because i want to see all timeframes up to now or a certain point in time.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon mentioned, you probably want a secondary table as a basis for ALL 5-minute intervals.  I have done similar with a query to self-build using MySQL variables.

```
select
      YourTable.WhateverFields
   from
      ( select
             @startTime RangeStart,
             @startTime := date_add( @startTime, interval 5 MINUTE ) RangeEnd
           from 
              ( select @startTime := '2014-10-20' ) sqlvars,
              AnyTableThatHasAsManyDaysYouExpectToReport
           limit
              12 * numberOfHoursYouNeed * numberOfDaysYouNeed ) DynamicTimeRange
         LEFT JOIN YourTable
            on YourTable.DateTimeField >= DynamicTimeRange.RangeStart
           AND YourTable.DateTimeField < DynamicTimeRange.RangeEnd
```

So, in this example, the innermost declars a variable "startTime" to Oct 20, 2014 which defaults to 12:00:00.  Then the one out from that creates a result set of two columns for a RangeStart and RangeEnd and might look something like...

```
RangeStart          RangeEnd
2014-10-20 00:00    2014-10-20 00:05
2014-10-20 05:00    2014-10-20 00:10
2014-10-20 10:00    2014-10-20 00:15
2014-10-20 05:00    2014-10-20 00:20
2014-10-20 20:00    2014-10-20 00:25
```

The table reference "AnyTableThatHasAsManyDaysYouExpectToReport"  is just that... any table in your database that has at least as many records as you would need to generate your 5-minute intervals for however many hours and days.  If you need 1 day worth = 12 records * 5 minutes = 1 hour * 24 hrs = 24*12 = 288 records needed.  If you wanted a week, then so be it... multiply that by 7 so my sample just has place-holders to help clarify the intent...

But with the LEFT JOIN, you get all the intervals...